# TSQL stored proc nonsense

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Saw this on a test- My SQL experience is basic CRUD-related and I'm not sure what the intent of this would be, if any?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetAccountID]
(
        @AccountID int = 1
)
AS
        SELECT @AccountID 
GO
```

What will be the output if the procedure is called as follows, and why?

`exec dbo.uspGetAccountID 5`

Comment: The result would be 5. @AccountID int = 1  setting a default value. So if you run you proc with 5 will return 5.

Comment: Indeed there is nonsense of this proc BUT it may used to had sense before changes occured and made it at this current state.

Comment: That was the obvious answer to me, but I ran it in Management Studio and it returned 0. Bigger question then became the intent for such a statement.

Comment: Yeah, of course it's 5. gbn explains the most probable reason why you might have mistaken it for zero. Here is the sqlfiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cfa39/1

Comment: It doesn't deserve a down vote because it does show SSMS can bollix you up.

Answer (score 4):

The zero is not the result of the code, it is the [return value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx)

SSMS actually generates this

```
USE [MyDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[uspGetAccountID] 
        @AccountID = 5

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

So you would have had 2 result sets. One for code, one for the return code

Add a `RETURN 42` to the code in the procedure after the `SELECT`, you get 42 in the second result...

Comment: Thanks. I figured this was either a stupidly trivial exercise or was looking at some subtlety that I was unaware of.

Answer (score 0):

The result will be 5.

Default values on parameters are only assigned if no value has been provided.

> You can create a stored procedure with optional parameters by
>   specifying a default value for optional parameters. When the stored
>   procedure is executed, the default value is used if no other value has
>   been specified.

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189330%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a test stored procedure.  It takes a parameter called `@AccountID` with a default value of `1`.

```
exec dbo.uspGetAccountID 5
```

Would result in `5` being selected.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec [dbo].[uspGetAccountID] 
-- should result in 1
exec [dbo].[uspGetAccountID] 5
-- should result in 5
```